# Typecasting in SpEL expresssion used in Spring Integration

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, spring-integration, spring-el

I need to add a prefix to every message that goes out. I can do it using a method, but would like to just have the transformer handle it.

The problem is the message needs to be prefixed with control code characters that I can't really type out and then some additional text.

For example:

```
private final static char EOT = (char) 4;
private final static char STX = (char) 2;
private final static char ETX = (char) 3;
private final static String additionalText = "          -0000 9305";
```

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes

Then the message would be prefixed with:

```
EOT + additionalText + ETX;
```

However, I can't find how to typecast the control codes in a SpEL expression used in the transformer:

```
<int:transformer
    id="prefixAdder"
    input-channel="initialMessage"
    output-channel="prefixAdded"
    expression="'#{(char) 4}' + '          -0000 9305' + '#{(char) 3}' + payload"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpEL doesn't support that directly; you could add a `<bean/>` that prefixes the control data, and use `expression="@prefixer.prefixPreamble(payload)"`.

```
public class Prefixer {
    public String prefix(String payload) {
        return prefix + payload;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was already using the ref/method attributes of transformer that look that they do essentially the same thing. I was just trying to get away with adding the prefix without having any additional beans.